# Flutter (for web) - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString') - how fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flutter app for web. x works on the local server, but I get an error on the working server (when booting) - I only see a white screen. This is the output from the console (chrome):

```
 Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic.
main.dart.js:59734 TrustedTypes available. Creating policy: flutterfire-firebase_core
VM314:2 Initializing Firebase firebase_core
main.dart.js:59734 TrustedTypes available. Creating policy: flutterfire-firebase_messaging
VM315:2 Initializing Firebase firebase_messaging
main.dart.js:4307 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
    at ayv.al0 (main.dart.js:107903:3)
    at main.dart.js:107881:11
    at aSi.a (main.dart.js:5676:62)
    at aSi.$2 (main.dart.js:46960:14)
    at Object.u (main.dart.js:5662:10)
    at ayv.a9U (main.dart.js:107885:10)
    at ayv.Ic (main.dart.js:107873:19)
    at main.dart.js:107868:33
    at aSi.a (main.dart.js:5676:62)
    at aSi.$2 (main.dart.js:46960:14)
```

"Cannot read properties of null" - means that some value has null (which is not expected). but how to understand what is the reason? how to find the cause of the error?

- the application works locally
- I tried to disable firebase - it didn't help
- previously everything also worked (on the working server)
- recently I updated to flutter 3.19 - I thought that was the reason. I downgraded to 3.16 - but the problem persists.
- I also used

  ```
  flutter clean
  ```
- This is my command for build release

  ```
  flutter build web --web-renderer html
  ```

any advice - I will be grateful